# Baking a Blender modifer to shape keys

Tags: python, animation, export, bezier-curves

I am attempting to export a mesh with a build modifier on it to an gITF animation (to simulate a motion trail). I currently create a curve with the movement data, convert to mesh, and then use the build modifier to animate the motion trail.  Since the animation is modifier based, it does not output to the gITF animation. Is there any way to either bake this modifier to shape keys at each keyframe (either through the GUI or through scripting) or an easier way to animate this that will export in the gITF format? The goal is to export the entire animation to a format that I can display in a webpage (full animated).

I am writing a Python library for dynamic visualization in Blender, so I would prefer any solution to not require any external add-ons, but I will consider them if necessary (only if they are free/open source).

I have attached the blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/13A2UVxGV36B66OheCyIsyujuG2zcR4uz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Could you share anim gif of your result? Your blend requires modul installation ...  I'm not experienced with glTF ... but what converts modifiers into anim mesh is Alembic format (.abc) so try that  ...if import .abc can be exported as glTF ... BTW export into shape keys (if possible) would require to animate appearance of shape keys that sounds like tedious work (if not handled by python).

Comment: I've exported Alembic fine, but the textures vanish. My fallback idea was to export to Alembic, re-texture and then export, but I wanted to see if there was a less convoluted way. As for the gif, I'll render it out soon and attach a link.